# Python download files from dropbox

Tags: python

I am trying to download shared files from Dropbox to my jupyter notebook. 
But it's giving me error 'saving disabled'. 
code,

```
import os
import urllib.request
def download(url):
     filename = url.split("/")[-1]
     if not os.path.exists(filename):
         urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)          download('my shared folder link dl=1')
```

Comment: You could use the DropBox API.  Pretty easy to use and has builtin functions to do all of this.

Comment: thanks, Any idea how to download data from AWS S3 bucket to jupyter home directory ?